# Flutter dart -> Capturar dados de uma classe que recebe json

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Boa galera?
Sou iniciante em flutter, e estou trabalhando com um template pronto.
Neste template eu tenho a classe category.dart que recebe os valores json de service.dart e até aqui está tudo ok.
O que eu preciso é chamar os dados da classe Category para dentro da classe AppData no aquivo data.dart substituindo assim os dados de exemplos fixos pelos dados dinâmicos.

**Service.dart**

```js
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:../src/model/category.dart';


class Connection {

  static const ROOT = 'http://localhost/get_category.php';
  static const _GET_ALL_ACTION = 'GET_ALL';
  static const _ADD_CAT_ACTION = 'ADD_CAT';
  static const _UPDATE_CAT_ACTION = 'UPDATE_CAT';
  static const _DELETE_CAT_ACTION = 'DELETE_CAT';

  static Future<List<Category>> getCategories() async {
    try {
      var map = Map<String, dynamic>();
      map['acao'] = _GET_ALL_ACTION;
      final response = await http.post(ROOT, body: map);
      print('getCategories -> Response :: ${response.body}');

      if(response.statusCode == 200) {
        List<Category> list = parseResponse(response.body);
        return list;
      }else{
        return List<Category>();
      }

    }catch (e) {
        return List<Category>();
    }
  }

  static List<Category> parseResponse(String response) {
    final parsed = json.decode(response).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    return parsed.map<Category>((json) => Category.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }
```

**category.dart**

```js
class Category{
  String id ;
  String name ;
  String image ;
  String description;
  bool isSelected;
  Category({this.id,this.name,this.image, this.description, this.isSelected});

  factory Category.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Category(
    id: json['cod'] as String,
    name: json['nome'] as String,
    image: json['thumb'] as String,
    description: json['descricao'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

**data.dart**

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:klug_ml/src/model/category.dart';

class AppData {
  static List<Category> categoryList = [
Category() //quero chamar os dados da categoria aqui

//Os dados dinâmicos, devem carregar como o exemplo abaixo.
Category(id:1,name: "Sneakers",image: 'assets/shoe_thumb_2.png',isSelected: true),
Category(id:2,name: "Jacket", image: 'assets/jacket.png'),
Category(id:3,name: "Watch", image: 'assets/watch.png'),

];
}
```

Chamada da Classe AppData no projeto.

```js
  Widget _categoryWidget() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      width: AppTheme.fullWidth(context),
      height: 80,
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: AppData.categoryList
            .map(
              (category) => ProductIcon(
                model: category,
                onSelected: (model) {
                  setState(() {
                    AppData.categoryList.forEach((item) {
                      item.isSelected = false;
                    });
                    model.isSelected = true;
                  });
                },
              ),
            )
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Seu código de busca na API então está todo correto do modo que vc quer não é? O problema que não sabe como fazer é só chamar o método que busca os dados da sua API? Se for apenas isso dentro da sua class AppData precisa existir um método que faça a chamada da API. Ele receberá a lista pronta pelo que está na sua implementação. Os dados do seu Category vão vir todos prontos. Não precisa fazer mais nada, vai apenas utilizar eles. Se não for essa sua dúvida comente aqui abaixo a parte que não entendeu pra que eu altere ou até remova minha resposta publicada.

Comment: É exatamente isso, não estou sabendo como chamar os dados para dentro de static List<Category> categoryList =  [ ]

Answer (score 0):

Segue exemplos:

```
void main() {
  String catJson = '{"cod": "1", "nome": "Sneakers","thumb":"assets/shoe_thumb_2.png"}';
  final catMap = jsonDecode(catJson);
  var cat = Category.fromJson(catMap);
  print(cat.name);

  
  Map<String, dynamic> catMap2 = {"cod": "1", "nome": "Sneakers","thumb":"assets/shoe_thumb_5.png"};
  cat = Category.fromJson(catMap2);
  print(cat.image);  
}
```

O primeiro exemplo é o que mais se adequa no caso de receber um `json`

Fonte:
https://dartpad.dev/32e42d2720b04b0bef90c5b38a8266d4

Comment: Desculpe minha ignorância, mais até agora ainda não compreendi. Editei o Post, coloquei também o código service.dart. Desde já agradeço sua contribuição.

Comment: Especifique o que exatamente não entendeu e o que exatamente deseja obter, pelo que entendi você está recebendo os dados de um serviço e quer transformar numa lista de objeto `Category`. Se for isso a outra resposta tem uma solução `chamadaNaApiRetornandoListaDeMaps` seria o seu `getCategories()`

 Caso seja seu primeiro contato com o `Dart` recomendo um estudo nos fundamentos da linguagem.

Answer (score 0):

A ideia inicial dessa "serialização" que montou no seu modelo é receber um `map` de algum método e transformar ele em objetos do tipo da classe. Então você vai construir um `Category` a partir de um `Map`.

**# Editado**

Na sua classe `AppData` é onde será feita a chamada do método que retorna dados da API:

```dart
void main() {
  final appData = AppData();

  appData.metodoQueBuscaDadosNaApi();
}

class AppData {
  List<Category> categoryList = [];

  Future<void> metodoQueBuscaDadosNaApi() async {
    final categorias = await Connection.getCategories();

    // Preencher a lista de categorias aqui
    categoryList = categorias;

    for(final categoria in categoryList){
      print(categoria.name);
    }
  }
}

class Connection {
  static Future<List<Category>> getCategories() async {
    // Aqui é apenas uma simulação para o POST da requisição
    // esses dados são exemplo apenas
    final categorias = [
      Category(name: "Cat 1"),
      Category(name: "Cat 2"),
      Category(name: "Cat 3"),
    ];

    return categorias;
  }
}

class Category {
  String id;
  String name;
  String image;
  String description;
  bool isSelected;
  Category({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.image,
    this.description,
    this.isSelected,
  });

  factory Category.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Category(
      id: json['cod'] as String,
      name: json['nome'] as String,
      image: json['thumb'] as String,
      description: json['descricao'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

Vá até o [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/) e cole todo esse código. Assim poderá entender melhor o funcionamento e até brincar com a implementação para ajustar a sua necessidade.

Comment: Desculpe minha ignorância, mais até agora ainda não compreendi. Editei o Post, coloquei também o código service.dart. Desde já agradeço sua contribuição.

Comment: Então basta chamar? Como se trata de uma lista, não teria de criar um loop? Se não como ficaria essa chamada?

Comment: Na parte colocada como comentário eu citei que pode ser feito outros tratamentos. Dentre eles pode sim utilizar um loop. É programação normal essa parte. Seu método que busca dados da Api tem a assinatura o retorno de uma lista. Logo quando receber essa lista pode fazer qualquer tratamento que faria com qualquer lista.

Comment: Sua classe `Connection` possui o método que faz o post e esse método foi declarado como `static`. A chamada dele então seria `await Connection.getCategories()`. Recomendo verificar na documentação a parte de realizar requisições http para melhor entendimento do tema. Exemplos prontos são excelentes para referências mas não são os melhores para iniciar no conceito.

Comment: Então até ai está tudo certo, o que eu não estou conseguindo fazer é passar a lista de dados de metodoQueBuscaDadosNaApi() para static List<Category> categoryList = [ ]

Comment: Pegue o exemplo que está agora na resposta. Atualizei novamente para que veja em funcionamento. Cole ele no Dartpad que está com o link no final da resposta e veja o funcionamento. Faça os testes que achar necessário.

Comment: Não consegui receber os dados, será que é porque minha variável categoyList é do tipo static?
static List<Category> categoryList = [];

Se retiro os static recebo  Error: Getter not found: 'categoryList'.
                    AppData.categoryList.forEach((item)

Comment: Mas no exemplo que eu postei não tem nenhum `static`, o exemplo não funcionou pra vc não? Pq vc quer que esse categoryList seja da classe e não da instância da classe? Como vc está usando a Classe `AppData` no seu projeto?

Comment: Veja no post editado, como é chamada a classe AppData no projeto. Grato